# Raspberry Pi reading current sent to pin is wrong after reboot

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

When I run the script below to turn the light on (state=on), then run the script again after rebooting the raspberry pi it tells me the state=on, when it should say off. Why does this happen? Is there any way I can fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
#setup GPIO using Board numbering. pin physical number corresponds to gpio call
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

pin=8
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

state = GPIO.input(pin)
#print 'START: state is: ',state

if state==1:
    GPIO.output(pin, False) #lov current turns relay on which breaks circuit on NC and changes state to off
    status="off"
else:
    GPIO.output(pin, True)
    status="on"

print 'light is now: ',status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke `GPIO.cleanUp();`

Here is a nice article explaining when/why/where: [RPi.GPIO basics 3 – How to Exit GPIO programs cleanly, avoid warnings and protect your Pi.](http://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-basics-3-how-to-exit-gpio-programs-cleanly-avoid-warnings-and-protect-your-pi)

Comment: That is definitely the answer, is the correct way to handle this situation to keep the program running then terminate it via sigint and call cleanup? Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @Rilcon42 I'm not an UNIX expert but using sigint seems like a valid option. Keep in mind that when your power gets cut off, your clean up won't happen. Simular issue: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=63051&p=467198